# Update another cell in the same row after editing inside DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I have two Textboxes **Discount(%)** and **Price(€)**. **Price** is *ReadOnly*.
The Row in the *DataGrid* has been built via a class called *MyData* and **Discount** is bound to the value *discount*, **Price** to *price*. When I change the percantage value of **Discount** it should calculate the new price and change the source-value *price* to the new price. But it doesn't update the textbox *price*. What do I need to call to trigger the update on target?

Xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Discount(%)" Width="0.5*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="tbDiscount" Text="{Binding Path=discount, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="tbDiscount_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Price (€)" Width="0.5*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Name="tbPrice" Text="{Binding Path=price, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

C#:

*MyData:*

```
public class MyData
{
    public decimal price { set; get; }
    public int discount { get; set; }
}
```

how I add the row to **DataGrid**

```
dataRow.discount = 0;
dataRow.price = price;
dataGridBasket.Items.Add(dataRow);
```

how I try to change the *price* value on textvalueChanged in TextBox **Discount**:

```
private void tbDiscount_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var text = sender as TextBox;

    text.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();

    foreach(MyData item in dataGridBasket.Items)
    {
        item.price = item.price - (item.price * (Convert.ToDecimal(item.discount) / 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: the logic of changing price should be in MyData class in `discount` setter. set new `price` value there and raise PropertyChangedEvent in `price` setter

Comment: also: why tbDiscount_TextChanged updates all dataGridBasket.Items when Discount was changed for only 1 item?

Comment: @ASh because I don't know how it works best. New to DataBinding...I don't know how to get the other specific Textbox so I tried to just update every single one. Thank you anyways

Comment: @ASh how would this setter method look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logic of changing price should be in `MyData` class in `discount` setter. set new `price` value there and raise `PropertyChangedEvent` in `price` setter.

you also need to store original price in some field/property to calculate discounted price properly.

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private decimal _basePrice;
    public decimal basePrice
    {
       get { return _basePrice; }
       set { _basePrice = value;  UpdatePrice(); }
    }

    private decimal _price;
    public decimal price
    {
       get { return _price; }
    }

    private int _discount;
    public int discount
    {
       get { return _discount; }
       set { _discount = value; UpdatePrice(); }
    }

    private void UpdatePrice()
    {
         _price = _basePrice * (100 - _discount) * 0.01M;
        OnPropertyChanged("price");
    } 
}
```

`tbDiscount_TextChanged` becomes redundant and DataGrid columns definitions can be simplified:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Discount(%)" Width="0.5*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=discount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price (€)"
                    Width="0.5*"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=price}"
                    IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Unfortunately it is not working properly. On beginning I set baseprice. In XAML I set the binding on textValueChanged to discount. But I go followed failure message:

Unhandled Exception: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: line "51" and line"108" from "the valur of "System.Windows.Data.Binding" cause an exception.". ---> System.InvalidCastException: the object of the type "System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo" can not be converted in "System.Reflection.MethodInfo".

Comment: sorry entered to early. See above :)

Comment: `TextChanged="tbDiscount_TextChanged"` can be removed from xaml too, since we don't need that event handler anymore

Comment: yes, I removed it. sorry missspelled it is line 51 and position 108...nevertheless it is followed line of xaml:

<TextBox Name="tbDiscount" Text="{Binding Path=discount, Mode=TwoWay}" TextChanged="{Binding Path=discount, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>

When I don't use "TextChange" it is doing nothing. should I remove "Text"?

Comment: @flyingAlemannian, check edits. TwoWay binding can not be created for property `price`, because it doesn't have setter now. note also `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in `discount` binding. it allows to update `price` after each change

Comment: I just put the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in `Textchange` instead of `Text`. Now it works. Thanks for your fantastic help!